# Intercepting SockJS non-websocket connection closure at HTTP session invalidation

Tags: sockjs, spring-websocket

the application I'm writing is using Spring Websocket support and enables SockJS to support non-websocket-capable clients.

According to the Java Websocket specification, when the HTTP session gets invalidated, WebSocket connections originated in that session gets closed automatically. However, nothing in Spring documentation describe what happens when SockJs has chosen not to use websockets for its connection.

So far, I see non-websocket connections getting closed as a result of the CSRF token becoming invalid, however I'd say this works only for short-lasting connections, not for long-lasting connection. I need to have all the "push" connections closed as soon as possible when the session becomes invalid.

Also, I will need to issue a "farewell" message to the client over their subcriptions immediately before the connection gets closed. How can I do this?

EDIT: adding some more information as I fear I have been too terse.

I'm using the full-featured broker to relay subscriptions to a backend ActiveMQ instance. I need the farewell message to be sent over the user's subscriptions and not to any other user's subscriptions, even though subcriptions are the same.

Roght now, if using user destinations, I was thninking of creating an `ApplicationListener` for event `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`, retrieving the username and using `SimpMessagingTemplate` to send the message.

Is there a way to do this without using user subscriptions (maybe some interceptor?) ?

EDIT 2: it looks like non-websocket connections gets closed too at a first sight, however I'm not sure if both "streaming" and "polling" like connections (see https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/tree/0.3.x#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https ). Can anyone point me to the code in Spring Websocket that supposedly should cut connections/subscriptions when a user session is invalidated?

Comment: Would http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/ help you in this case?

Comment: I'll take look at it, but I'm not using Spring Session, just the standard session support in Spring/Spring Security.

Comment: @BrianClozel I check spring-session out but I cannot use it, because unfortunately Spring Session does not trigger `HttpSessionCreatedEvent` and `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`, because it does not support `HttpSessionListeners`, and I need those events (a part for issueing the farewell message) to handle session management.